# Mariadb connection client: Access denied for user (using password: NO) on mysql 8.0

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

mariadb-java-client throws access denied on mysql 8.0, but works on mysql 5.6
So I wonder if mariadb client is compatible with mysql 8.0

1. in mysql, test users are set limit to hosts machine = %
2. even tested on mysql 8.0's machine, same access denied error.

---

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user1'@'192.168.238.1' (using password: NO)
Current charset is UTF-8. If password has been set using other charset, consider using option 'passwordCharacterEncoding'
```

---

```
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://192.168.0.2:3306/test", "user1", "admin@123");
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE a (id int not null primary key, value varchar(20))");
    stmt.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE a");
    stmt.close();
    connection.close();
```

Same user name and password on mysql 5.6 and 8.0

1. Succeeded: 'mariadb-java-client', version: '2.3.0', mysql 5.6
2. Failed:    'mariadb-java-client', version: '2.3.0', mysql 8.0
3. Succeeded: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.13' mysql 8.0 (jdbc:mysql://....)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MySQL 8 uses caching_sha2_password rather than mysql_native_password as of MySQL 5.7 (and MariaDB).

"caching_sha2_password, it is as of MySQL 8.0 the preferred authentication plugin, and is also the default authentication plugin rather than mysql_native_password. This change affects both the server and the libmysqlclient client library:"

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password

MariaDB's Java Connector does not yet implement this, but has a task assigned:

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-663

In order to connect to MySQL 8, you will have to use the Oracle connector,  another connector that supports the change, or wait for MariaDB to implement.

Comment: Thanks... i updated my Mysql user password with "mysql_native_password" and it worked.  ```ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost'
  IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
  BY 'password'; ```