# DBeaver can't connect mariadb in docker some error with charset

Tags: docker, mariadb, dbeaver

I run docker-compose up with this docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'
services:
    mariadb:
        image: mariadb:10.6
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: P@ssw0rd
          MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
          MYSQL_USER: user
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        restart: always
        volumes:
         - ./mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
```

and it's works. (I try to connect container MySQL command line on my local machine window10)

But I can't connect with DBeaver(21.0.4) mariadb driver 2.7.1 message error:

```
(conn=28) Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Current charset is x-windows-874. If password has been set using other charset, consider using option 'passwordCharacterEncoding'
```

I try to set passwordCharacterEncoding 123456 in Driver properties, not works DBeaver error message 123456 instead from above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mariadb connection client: Access denied for user (using password: NO) on mysql 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188309/mariadb-connection-client-access-denied-for-user-using-password-no-on-mysql)

Comment: No, I try using SQLyog connect success. have a problem with DBeaver?